# Extreme values without taking the hessian matrix

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the extreme values of $f(x,y)=xye^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$.
Is there a way to solve this problem without taking any partial derivative?

We can rewrite $f(x,y)$ as
$$f(x,y)=xye^{xy}e^{-(x+y)^2/2}$$
but then an estimation is needed, maybe.

Comment: There are numerical methods to solve optimization problems  that are *derivative free* if that is what you mean. You can do a quick search about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates $x=r\sin(\theta), y=r\cos(\theta)$, so that after identifying $R := r^2/2$,
$$x\,y=r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=r^2\sin(2\theta)/2 = \sin(2\theta) \,R$$

So

$$x\,y\,{\mathrm e}^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}=\sin(2\theta)\ {\mathrm e}^{-R} R = \sin(2\theta)\int_{0}^{R}{\mathrm e}^{-x}(1-x)\,{\mathrm d}x$$

and that's extremal when $|\sin(2\theta)|=1$, i.e. along $\theta=(n+1/4)\cdot\pi$, which is where $x=\pm y$, and, via fundamental theorem of calculus, $R=1$, which is to say $r=\sqrt{2}$.

I mean you said "without using derivatives", so I suppose I cheated a bit when the integrand just falls out of the sky. (I mentally applied the product rule to ${\mathrm e}^{-x}x$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand how you get $R=1$.

Comment: @castagnegenge One way is to use the the fundamental theorem and argue that the integrand is the derivative. But it's also clear from the integral itself, since if the integral is positive $x$ from $0$ to $1$ but from that point on it would just accumulate negative values. (If x > 1, then $(1-x)<0$.)